# Controlar un servicio de windows desde icono barra de notificaciones

Tags: c#, wpf, servicio

Tengo desarrollado un servicio windows que funciona correctamente, pero para activarlo tengo que tirar algunos comandos del cmd y la verdad me gustaría que tuviera una activación/pausa mas amigable y tambien algunas notificaciones toast cuando se inicie, intente arrancar el servicio desde una aplicación de escritorio sencilla solo con un boton "Iniciar servicio" cuyo codigo es este:

```
private void IniciarProceso_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");
  if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running && 
  sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)
  {
    sc.Start();
  }
}
```

Pero al intentar iniciar el servicio recibo el error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se puede abrir el servicio MyService 
en el equipo '.'.'
Excepción interna
Win32Exception: Acceso denegado
```

Como le otorgo los permisos para poder iniciar/detener el servicio? es posible que esta aplicación quede oculta en el panel que esta al lado de la fecha y hora y de ahi mostrar notificaciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias subir los provilegios con los cuales ejecutas la aplicaicon para que lo haga como `local admin`.

Esto se logra por medio de `manifest`

[Force Windows Forms Application to Run As Administrator on Windows 7](http://www.codeease.com/posts/force-windows-form-application-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7.html)

Como observaras agregas el

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para poder descomentar la linea

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

y asi lograr que ejecute como admin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este nuevo provilegio deberia tener acceso a los servicio de windows

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha quedado solucionada la parte de inicio del servicio.